# Jenkins Gitlab plugin, execute pipeline on a merge request or on the master branch

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to get my Jenkins multi branch pipeline to get triggered by Gitlab :

- A push on the master branch
- Any merge request that gets opened

[Gitlab plugin Jenkins doc](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitlab-plugin/)

Webhook works fine and pipelines get executed fine too. Problem is they get executed by every commit. The triggers section in the doc is not clear on how I should implement this in a declarative pipeline.

```
gitlab(triggerOnPush: true, triggerOnMergeRequest: true, branchFilterType: 'NameBasedFilter', branchFilterName: 'master')
```

Jenkins doesn't accept a duplicate gitlab trigger. I want to triggerOnPush but only for branches that are in an open merge request. Also I want to triggerOnPush every commit in master branch.

Also I tried working with the `changeRequest()` in `when` conditional block but it doesn't work either.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

To always trigger a build for each commit in master only, under "Automatic branch project triggering", set the "Branch names to build automatically" to master and the "Suppression strategy" to "Nothing is suppressed".

For your second requirement, Projects > Repository Sources > Behaviors > Discover branches set the strategy to "Only branches that are also filed as PRs", which will build only the branches related to a merge request.